# VHDL implementation of debouncer

Tags: vhdl

as a part of my electonical classes i need to make clock in VHDL.
I managed to make seconds blinking in a dot between 7-segment display, and of course showing minutes and hours (hh:mm). But my last task is to add a button to set hours, and minutes. After couple hours with errors about signal sharing etc. i gave up ... :s and i know that VHDL is not for me for sure.
Could anyone tell me how to implement button with only one signal after click ?

---

```
-- Company: 
-- Engineer: 
-- 
-- Create Date:    21:33:34 05/20/2019 
-- Design Name: 
-- Module Name:    Zegar - Behavioral 
-- Project Name: 
-- Target Devices: 
-- Tool versions: 
-- Description: 
--
-- Dependencies: 
--
-- Revision: 
-- Revision 0.01 - File Created
-- Additional Comments: 
--
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity Zegar is

    Port (
    clock : in STD_LOGIC;
    reset : in STD_LOGIC;
    przycisk : inout STD_LOGIC;
    przycisk : inout STD_LOGIC;
    dot : out STD_LOGIC;
    anoda : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 3 downto 0);
    segm : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0)

    );
end Zegar;

architecture Behavioral of Zegar is

signal  sec : STD_LOGIC := '0';
signal  sekunda_ENABLE : STD_LOGIC := '0';
signal  minuta_ENABLE : STD_LOGIC := '0';
signal  minuta_DZ_ENABLE : STD_LOGIC := '0';
signal  godzina_ENABLE : STD_LOGIC := '0';

signal mux : STD_LOGIC := '0';
signal wysw : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0) := "00";
signal bcd : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);


signal minuta_jed : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0) := "0000";
signal minuta_dz : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0) := "0000";
signal godzina_jed : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0) := "0000";
signal godzina_dz : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0) := "0000";

begin

process(clock)

        VARIABLE counter : natural := 0;
        --sekundy
begin

        if(clock'event and clock = '1') then
                if(counter < 50000000) then
                        counter := counter + 1;
                else
                        sec <= not sec;
                        counter := 0;
                end if;
        end if;

end process;

--sekundy 
process(sec, reset)

        VARIABLE counter : natural  range 0 to 60;
begin
        if (reset = '1') then
                counter := 0;
        else if(sec'event and sec = '1') then
                if(counter < 59) then
                        counter := counter + 1;
                                sekunda_ENABLE <= '0';
                else
                        counter := 0;
                        sekunda_ENABLE <= '1';
                end if;
        end if;
end if;

end process;

--minuty jed
process(sekunda_ENABLE, reset)
begin
        if (reset = '1') then
                minuta_jed <= "0000";
        else if(sekunda_ENABLE'event and sekunda_ENABLE = '1') then
                if(minuta_jed < "1001") then
                        minuta_jed <= minuta_jed + 1;
                                minuta_ENABLE <= '0';
                else
                        minuta_jed <= "0000";
                        minuta_ENABLE <= '1';
                end if;
        end if;
end if;

end process;

--minuty dzies
process(minuta_ENABLE, reset)
begin
        if (reset = '1') then
                minuta_dz <= "0000";
        else if(minuta_ENABLE'event and minuta_ENABLE = '1') then
                if(minuta_dz < "0101") then
                        minuta_dz <= minuta_dz + 1;
                                minuta_DZ_ENABLE <= '0';
                else
                        minuta_dz <= "0000";
                        minuta_DZ_ENABLE <= '1';
                end if;
        end if;
end if;
end process;

--godziny jed

process(minuta_DZ_ENABLE, reset)
begin
        if (reset = '1') then
                godzina_jed <= "0000";
        else if(minuta_DZ_ENABLE'event and minuta_DZ_ENABLE = '1') then
                if(godzina_jed < "1001") then
                        godzina_jed <= godzina_jed + 1;
                                godzina_ENABLE <= '0';
                        if(godzina_jed = "0011" and godzina_dz = "0010") then
                                godzina_jed <= "0000";
                                godzina_ENABLE <= '1';
                        end if;
                else
                        godzina_ENABLE <= '1';
                        godzina_jed <= "0000";
                end if;
        end if;
end if;
end process;

--godzina dzies
process(godzina_ENABLE, reset)
begin
        if (reset = '1') then
                godzina_dz <= "0000";
        else if(godzina_ENABLE'event and godzina_ENABLE = '1') then
                if(godzina_dz < "0010") then
                        godzina_dz <= godzina_dz + 1;
                else
                        godzina_dz <= "0000";
                end if;
        end if;
end if;
end process;

--MUX licznik

process(clock)
        VARIABLE counter : natural :=0;
begin
        if(clock'event and clock = '1') then
                if(counter < 100000) then
                        counter := counter + 1;
                else
                        counter := 0;
                        mux <= not mux;
                end if;
        end if;
end process;


process(mux)
begin
        if(mux'event and mux = '1') then
            if(wysw < "11") then 
            wysw <= wysw + 1;
         else              
                wysw <= "00";
             end if;
        end if;

end process;
                with wysw select
                        anoda <= "1110" when "00",
                                                "1101" when "01",
                                                "1011" when "10",
                                                "0111" when "11",
                                                "1111" when others;

                                with anoda select
                                dot <= sec when     "1011",
                                                '1' when others;

                        with wysw select
                        bcd <= godzina_jed when "10",
                                         godzina_dz when "11",
                                         minuta_dz when "01",
                                         minuta_jed when "00",
                                         "1111" when others;

                        with bcd select
                        segm <=         "11000000" when "0000",
                                                "11111001" when "0001",
                                                "10100100" when "0010",
                                                "10110000" when "0011",
                                                "10011001" when "0100", 
                                                "10010010" when "0101",
                                                "10000010" when "0110",
                                                "11111000" when "0111",
                                                "10000000" when "1000",
                                                "10010000" when "1001",
                                                "11111111" when others; 

end Behavioral;>
```

I need to add signal after button press to the "--minuty jed" process or "--godziny jed". I tried to make another prescaler and make another "IF"
like "if button = '1' and anotherprescaler = '1'" then 
"minuta_jed <= minuta_jed + 1;"
  but i failed ...

Answer (score 2):

Whys of debounce:

1. Switches bounce.

   - This means that on make, they make, then break, then make, before finally settling out closed.
   - Ditto on break.  They break, then make, etc., before finally settling out open.
2. Different switches bounce differently.  The amount of time it takes for them to settle varies, as does the speed that they bounce.
3. Switches can bounce differently on make and break.  Some switches bounce on make but not break, or bounce for different lengths of time, or different periods.

Anything that's edge-triggered, i.e. that wants to count "switch presses" needs to filter out the switch bounce artifact from the actual switch press.

Ways to debounce:

1. Sample more slowly than the switch's settling time (with an interval > 2x the settling time).  This is easiest, and slowest.
2. Low-pass filter switch's state (turning the discrete variable into a continuous one) then run the result through a block with hysteresis.  Easy in analog, resource-consuming in digital.
3. Run the switch's raw state through a state machine with some delay.

I have a number of "best" algorithms for debounce, but to keep it simple you may want to just do the "sample it slowly" trick.  This is dead simple, reliable, and good enough for homework.